# Can't select last child in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to select first element `.tabs-heading` after last element with these classes `.tabs-heading .is-active`

And on that first element `.tabs-heading` without `is-active` class I want to add `is-active` class

I've tried this, but not working!

```
document.querySelector('#next-bt').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var firstInactive = document.querySelector('.tabs-heading.is-active:last-child + .tabs-heading');
    firstInactive.classList.add('is-active');
});
```

Comment: Some html will be helpful. We don't see how Yours document looks like.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the dom?

Comment: how does the html structure look like exactly?

Comment: there is no element after last-child ---> so this will never work

Comment: before saying it's not a duplicate : last-child, nth-child, nth-of-type all works the same way and you cannot combine selecor with them. They consider elements and not elements with a specific class. Also this has nothing to do with JS, you are using querySelector so it's a CSS issue

Comment: How many items with `is-active` do you have ?